# TypeError: "d is undefined" in angular when using translate pipe

Tags: angular, angular-translate

I got the error below if I'm using the translate pipe. The console output in `getFirstError` is always the key "required". The translation pipe works fine in the same html file in other lines.
Unfortunately the error message isn't helpful at all although I run in dev mode.

ts:

```
getFirstError() {
  console.log(Object.keys(this.f['description'].errors)[0]); 
  return 'validation.' + Object.keys(this.f['description'].errors)[0];
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf="f['description'].invalid" class="mat-error">
  {{ getFirstError() | translate}}
</div>
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: "d is undefined"
    required http://localhost:4200/vendor.js line 198734 > Function:21
    interpolateFunction http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:186889
    interpolate http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:186851
    getParsedResult http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:187284
    get http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:187331
    updateValue http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:187728
    transform http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:187769
    View_CourseFormComponent_2 ng:///CourseModule/CourseFormComponent.ngfactory.js:26
    debugUpdateRenderer http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:103324
    checkAndUpdateView http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:102307
    callViewAction http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:102667
```

Comment: Did you check the result of getFirstError() ? to me it seems like you send undefined in the translate pipe

Comment: Checked that. The result is never undefined.